# Detect if script is opened in temporary window

Tags: python, windows

I have quite a few programs designed for the cli, giving an output at the end of execution. Whenever I'm executing the program in cmd, a print statement at the end allows me to show the output and end the program.

If I'm double clicking the script in explorer, though, it opens a temporary window which will close after the program is complete, in which case I want to output using input().

At first, I thought I might be calling `pythonw.exe` when opening using the explorer, but the only difference in the process tree that I could find is that either `cmd.exe` is used, or it isn't.

This difference would be sufficient in my case, but I'm curious if there's some other way to know whether the temporary window is open, which closes after the script is done, or any cli is open, that doesn't close.

So, in conclusion, I want a way to detect this difference that is more general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research, and figured out what's being called exactly, when double clicking to launch the "temporary window".

The command being run is `"C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*"` where `%L` is the full path of the program being run, and `%*` is parameters that are passed on when executing this file type. Furthermore, I've installed and used Process Explorer in order to look at the exact process structure, showing that the two ways to run the program have the following process structures

```
└─py.exe
  ├─conhost.exe
  └─python.exe
```

and

```
└─cmd.exe
  ├─conhost.exe
  └─py.exe
    └─python.exe
```

By thinking about it a little, I realize, that `conhost.exe` is what's being used in both cases to provide the type of window, and that this means, that the meaningful difference is, whether an instance of `conhost.exe` is being created by `py.exe`, or if it or some other executable of similar use is being used, usually as a sibling of `py.exe`.

In a program, this way of distinguishing may be done like this:

```py
import psutil
proc = psutil.Process() # python.exe
in_cmd = True
for proc in proc.parent().children(): # siblings of python.exe
    if proc.name() == "conhost.exe":
        in_cmd = False # can be used whenever for behavioral differences
        break
```

In conclusion, this means that what really matters, is the presence of `conhost.exe` as a child of `py.exe`, making this a more general answer.